# VB.NET and Json, Deserialize preserved keywords

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have a problem with vbnet and json. I'm trying to get some information from a restservice. The restservice return this json string:

```
{
  "Default": 1,
  "Date": "2015-01-26T00:00:00+01:00",
}
```

I want to deserialize this response, doing something like:

```
Dim result As myclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of myclass (responseText)
```

The problem is that "Default" and "Date" are preserved keywords, so i cannot define this class:

```
Public Class myclass 
    Public Property Date As Datetime
    Public Property Default as String
End Class
```

I cannot modify de restservice, so How can I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [VB.NET spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa711644):

> Regular identifiers may not match keywords, but escaped identifiers can.

So instead of

```
Public Class myclass 
    Public Property Date As Datetime
    Public Property Default as String
End Class
```

you can use *escaped identifier* using square brackets like this

```
Public Class [myclass]
    Public Property [Date] As Datetime
    Public Property [Default] as String
End Class
```

---

Another solution is to use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm)

```
Public Class SomeClass 
    <JsonProperty("Date")>
    Public Property TheDate As Datetime
    <JsonProperty("Default")>
    Public Property SomethingDefault as String
End Class
```